# While and Try Catch Loop Error Java

Tags: java, loops

I'm trying to create a simple player selection loop, but when if the user attempts to input something that isn't an integer, the loop "falls throw" in a sense. I don't know what I need to do so this code doesn't fall throw in case of an inappropriate input.

```
int player;
boolean playerCreated = false;
while (playerCreated == false) {
  try {
    player = scan.nextInt();
      if (player != 1 && player != 2) {
        throw new Exception();
      }
    playerCreated = true;
  }
catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println("Please input a valid player selection. (1 or 2)");
  continue;
  }
}
```

Comment: `throw new Exception()` is as bad as `catch (Exception e)`, both should be avoided. There is zero need to throw an exception in your case. For all other exceptions other than your own you just throw away the potentially important and informative error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you enter a type other than an interger type when you type, an exception will be thrown before the if statement is encountered. Therefore, it does not work on the catch statement specified below.

If you handle an exception in a catch statement, continue will cause the scan to hold the value and cause the content of the catch statement to be infinite. Therefore, you need to initialize the scan when the while statement starts.

```
while (playerCreated == false) {
try {
scan=new Scanner(System.in);
player = scan.nextInt();
  if (player != 1 && player != 2) {
    throw new Exception();
  }
playerCreated = true;
}
```

Comment: this is a bad idea, especially since neither you nor the user close the scanner

Comment: @tima What is the proper way to avoid this issue?

Comment: @Karlov use one scanner, close the scanner in the finally block or use a try with resources block; clear / skip the input in the scanner when it is invalid

Comment: @tima If you finally close the scanner after the catch statement, and then restart the scanner at the beginning of the while statement, it will be a bit cleaner code.

Comment: @MinKyuJeong you have to close the scanner to prevent memory leaks not for cleaner code